# SVG path will not show when inserted using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

I'm trying to fiddle around with google maps. 
I lifted a great example online that utilised map overlay instead of the markers to allow for more tailored markers.
I've done this because I want to animate the marker from  one svg path to another.
Problem: when I insert the svg the svg shows, but no path/shape etc.

```
       <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>

    <title>Google Maps API</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    .icon-container {
      background-color:yellow;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      position:absolute;
    }

    #icon {
      position:absolute;
      width:30px;
      height:30px;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes example {
        0% {opacity: 0; width: 30px; height: 30px;}
        50% {opacity: 0.5; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
        100% {opacity: 1; width: 30px; height: 30px;}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes example2 {
        0% {opacity: 1; width: 30px; height: 30px;}
        50% {opacity: 0.5; width: 15px; height: 15px;}
        100% {opacity: 0; width: 0px; height: 0px;}
    }

    #icon.show{
      -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration:1.5s;
      opacity:1;
    }

    #icon.show{-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}

    #icon.show.alter {
      -webkit-animation-name: example2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration:1.5s;
    }

    #icon.show.hide {
      -webkit-animation-name: example2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration:1.5s;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    #map-canvas {
      width: 700px;
      height: 400px;
    }

    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="CustomGoogleMapMarker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.9546781,115.852662);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: myLatlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true
      }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      /*
      // Example standard marker
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
      */

      overlay = new CustomMarker(
        myLatlng, 
        map,
        {
          marker_id: '123'
        }
      );
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="map-canvas"> </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" id="show-button">Show</button>
        <button type="button" id="active-button">Active</button>
        <button type="button" id="hide-button">Hide</button>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please excuse the inline css and js, I'm just testing and got annoyed at this... 
JS

//Creating a custom marker

```
            function CustomMarker(latlng, map, args) {
                this.latlng = latlng;   
                this.args = args;   
                this.setMap(map);   
            }
            //extends overlay view and inherits its methods
            CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

            CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function() {

                var self = this;

                var div = this.div;

                if (!div) {

                    div = this.div = document.createElement('div');

                    div.className = 'marker';

                    div.style.position = 'absolute';
                    div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                    div.style.width = '20px';
                    div.style.height = '20px';

                    svg = this.svg = document.createElement('svg');
                    svg.version="1.1";
                    svg.className = 'icon-container';
                    svg.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 300 300");
                    svg.style.height = "300px";
                    svg.style.width = "300px";
                    svg.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
                    svg.setAttribute("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
                    svg.setAttribute("x", "0px");
                    svg.setAttribute("y", "0px");
                    svg.setAttribute("enable-background", "new 0 0 300 300");
                    svg.setAttribute("xml:space", "preserve");

                    moveOne = this.moveOne = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path");
                    moveOne.setAttribute("fill", "none");
                    moveOne.setAttribute("stroke", "#231F20");
                    moveOne.setAttribute("stroke-miterlimit", "10");
                    moveOne.setAttribute("d", "M141.674,237.632");

                    moveTwo = this.moveTwo = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path");
                    moveTwo.setAttribute("fill", "none");
                    moveTwo.setAttribute("stroke", "#231F20");
                    moveTwo.setAttribute("stroke-miterlimit", "10");
                    moveTwo.setAttribute("d", "M47.891,113.798");

                    icon = this.icon = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path");
                    icon.setAttribute('id','icon');
                    icon.setAttribute("d", "M201.223,100.373c0,50.655-41.954,72.492-72.28,72.492 c-48.548,0-72.28-31.951-72.28-72.492c0-39.919,32.361-72.28,72.28-72.28C168.862,28.093,201.223,60.454,201.223,100.373z");
                    icon.setAttribute("fill", "#000");
                    icon.setAttribute("stroke-miterlimit","10");
                    icon.style.position = "absolute";

                    svg.appendChild(moveOne);
                    svg.appendChild(moveTwo);
                    svg.appendChild(icon);
                    div.appendChild(svg);

                    if (typeof(self.args.marker_id) !== 'undefined') {
                        div.dataset.marker_id = self.args.marker_id;
                    }

                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function(event) {;
                        console.log("click");
                        console.log(this);
                        this.className += " click";
                    });

                    var panes = this.getPanes();
                    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
                }

                var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng);

                if (point) {
                    div.style.left = (point.x - 10) + 'px';
                    div.style.top = (point.y - 20) + 'px';
                }
            };

            CustomMarker.prototype.remove = function() {
                if (this.div) {
                    this.div.parentNode.removeChild(this.div);
                    this.div = null;
                }   
            };

            CustomMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {
                return this.latlng; 
            };

            function init(){

                $('#show-button').click(function() {
                    console.log("show the icon");
                    $('#icon').addClass('show');
                });

                $('#active-button').click(function() {
                    console.log("alter the icon");
                });

                $('#hide-button').click(function() {
                    console.log("hide the icon");
                });
            }



            $(document).ready(init);
```

The reason I've added the 2 random move paths is because thats how it looks in the html from my svg image saved from illustrator, I know it shouldn't be necessary but as an  svg displays, but inserting a hand written svg doesn't I thought I'd try to mimic it.

I need to use a path, because i want to animate a circle to a point, like the marker is growing. In order to animate the points I cannot use the image method, I'll have to use the path and animate the path.

Any ideas why inserting that style SVG won't work? Is it a google maps thing/javascript thing? Should i attempt to try snap or d3?

any thoughts would be great as i just can't see why it refuses to show the path (or any other shape):)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i accidentally deleted it, but a user said that I hadn't put the NS after the createElement for my SVG. they were correct. If it was my fault on accidentally deleting, if you post up I'll get you the tick and good points for noticing my foolish error- thanks so much!!